# detect shake event on iphone

Tags: javascript, ios

I'm trying to detect a shake event on iPhone. [shake.js library](https://github.com/alexgibson/shake.js) is not working, would appreciate any help or other solutions. I've also tried [this](https://dev.to/li/how-to-requestpermission-for-devicemotion-and-deviceorientation-events-in-ios-13-46g2) but no luck.

```
function ClickRequestDeviceMotionEvent () {
window.DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission()
.then(response => {
  if (response === 'granted') {
    window.addEventListener('devicemotion',
      () => { 
          //alert('DeviceMotion permissions granted.'); 
          
          var o = 0.6; // 0
          var myShakeEvent = new Shake ({
            threshold: 10, // 15. optional shake strength threshold
            timeout: 1000 // optional, determines the frequency of event generation
          });
          
          myShakeEvent.start(); // mobile, no ipad

          window.addEventListener('shake', shakeEventDidOccur, false);
          
          function shakeEventDidOccur() { // function to call when shake occurs
            alert('shake!');
          } 
      },
      (e) => { throw e }
  )} else {
    alert('DeviceMotion permissions not granted.')
  }
})
.catch(e => {
  alert(e)
})
```

}

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, this isn't possible anymore.

Shake.js was discontinued so is not supported.

Also, Safari does not support the Accelerometer, Gyroscope or the DeviceMotionEvent web API's, so this data is just not available for your code to react to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So seems no other way using JS?

Comment: Doesn't appear to be anything official. Best place to look is [the Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web), either under JS or Web APIs, but I can't find anything that would be of use.